# Why can't this function work to replace elements in a list?

Tags: python, list, function, loops, lambda

Trying to change all 5's into 100's. I know you should use list comprehension but why doesn't this work? Someone can explain theoretically? Thank you.

```
d = [5,1,1,1,5]

def f1(seq):
    for i in seq:
        if i==5:
            i = 100
    return seq

print (f1(d))
```

Comment: `i` has the same value as an item in the sequence. But it's a separate variable. Reassigning it doesn't affect the sequence.

Comment: i is the copy not actual item

Comment: @VazgenTorosyan. `i` is not a copy, it is a reference to the original item, but it has nothing to do with the list.

Comment: @MadPhysicist So `i` has a different id than the item in the list?

Comment: @MrSoLoDoLo `i` initially has the same `id` as the item in the list. But when you say, `i = 100`, it will now point `i` to a different object (an `int` with a value of 100). The reference in the list will still be pointing to the `int` with value 5 it was pointing to originally though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Python assignment operator binds a value to a name. Your loop `for i in seq` binds a value from `seq` to the local name `i` on every iteration. `i = 100` then binds the value `100` to `i`. This does not affect the original sequence, and the binding will be changed again in the next iteration of the loop.

You can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to list the indices along with the values of `seq` and perform the binding that way:

```
def f1(seq):
    for i, n in enumerate(seq):
        if n == 5:
            seq[i] = 100
    return seq
```

Even simpler may be to just iterate over the indices:

```
def f2(seq):
    for i in range(len(seq)):
        if seq[i] == 5:
            seq[i] = 100
    return seq
```

The options shown above will modify the sequence in-place. You do not need to return it except for convenience. There are also options for creating a new sequence based on the old one. You can then rebind the variable `d` to point to the new sequence and drop the old one.

The easiest and probably most Pythonic method would be using a list comprehension:

```
d = [5, 1, 1, 1, 5]
d = [100 if x == 5 else x for x in d]
```

You can also use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
d = list(map(lambda x: 100 if x == 5 else x, d))
```

The output of `map` is a generator, so I have wrapped it in `list` to retain the same output type. This would not be necessary in Python 2, where `map` already returns a list.

Answer (score 4):

This line:

```
i = 100
```

Gives the local variable `i`, which was originally assigned that value in `seq`,  the value `100`.

To change the value in the sequence, you could do:

```
for index, object in enumerate(seq):
    if object == 5:
        seq[index] = 100
```

Enumerate returns two objects each time it is  called on a sequence, the index as a number, and the object itself.

See the docs on lists and (Python 2) [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html).

You could have also written:

```
for index in range(len(seq)):
    if seq[index] == 5:
        seq[index] = 100
```

Which you may prefer, but is sometimes considered less clean.

Answer (score 2):

You should update the element at the list, like that:

```
def f1(seq):
    for i in range(len(seq)): # run through the indexes of the list
        if seq[i]==5: # check whether seq at index i is 5
            seq[i] = 100 # update the list at the same index to 100

    return seq
```

`i` is a new variable created inside the loop, therefore it's not the same reference as the element inside the list.

**NOTE:**

Note that list is a mutable object, therefore changing seq inside the function will affect the list even outside the function.

You can read more about mutable and immutable in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056130/immutable-vs-mutable-types)

Comment: Good job on resuscitating your answer :)

Comment: Yeap, I was confused before.. well, it's a long day :) @MadPhysicist

Answer (score 1):

Take the following example:

```
def f1(seq):
    for i in seq:
        if i==5:
            i = 100
        # at this point (assuming i was 5), i = 100 but seq is still [3,5,7]
        # because i is not a reference to the item but the value *copied* from the list
    ...
f1([3,5,7])
```

You could instead loop through the indices and set the value at that index in the list:

```
d = [5,1,1,1,5]

def f1(seq):
    for i in range(len(seq)):
        if seq[i]==5:
            seq[i] = 100
    return seq

print(f1(d))
# [100,1,1,1,100]
```